# $1\le \frac{x'}{y'}\le \frac{x}{y}$, then $\frac{1+x'}{1+y'}\le \frac{1+x}{1+y}$

Tags: inequality

For any non-negative $x, x', y, y'$, if $x'\le x$ and $1\le \frac{x'}{y'}\le \frac{x}{y}$, then $\frac{1+x'}{1+y'}\le \frac{1+x}{1+y}$.

How to prove it?

I expanded the goal and simplified it to $x+y'+xy'-x'-y-x'y\ge 0$.

Then if $y'\ge y$，we have $x\ge x', y'\ge y, xy'\ge x'y$，i.e. $x+y'+xy'-x'-y-x'y\ge 0$

But when $y'\le y$, I attempted to magnify or shrink elements in the target, but was unsuccessful in resolving it. I would appreciate some hints.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: For the given inequalities to make sense and to hold, each of $x,x',y,y'$ must be positive (not just non-negative).

Comment: @JohnBentin The question says, "For any non-negative $x, x', y, y'$, ... and $1\le \frac{x'}{y'}\le \frac{x}{y}$." This latter assumption implicitly states that none of $x, x', y, y'$ can be zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are simpler ways, but here is my solution.

Lemma: If $\frac{\color{red}{a}}{\color{blue}{b}} = \frac{\color{blue}{c}}{\color{red}{d}}$ and $b\leq a\leq c,$ then $\color{red}{a}+\color{red}{d}\leq \color{blue}{b}+\color{blue}{c}.$

Proof: $a\leq c,$ so $\ \exists\ \lambda \geq 1$ such that $c=\lambda a$ and $d=\lambda b.\quad b \leq a$ and $\lambda\geq 1,$ so $a-b \leq \lambda(a-b),\ \implies \lambda b + a \leq \lambda a + b,\ $ i.e. $d + a \leq b + c.\blacksquare$

Since $y'\leq x'\leq x,$ applying the Lemma to $\frac{x'}{y'} = \large{\frac{x}{\frac{xy'}{x'}}},$ gives us $x'+\frac{xy'}{x'} \leq x+y'.\ $ But $y\leq \frac{xy'}{x'},$ and so $\boxed{x' + y\leq x+y'}.$ Since also $1+x'y\leq 1+y'x,$ it follows that $1+x' + y +x'y \leq 1+ y' + x + y'x,\implies (1+x')(1+y)\leq (1+x)(1+y'),$ and the result folows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and the lemma is really clever.

Comment: You're welcome. The lemma is nice, yes. I couldn't see another way to prove it. I'm also sure there is a more succinct way of presenting my proof, but I don't see it.